# What is the most common default computer name (sys properties)

Tags: networking, windows-xp, windows

What is the most common default computer name for Windows (Home, Pro, Vista, and 7)?
(Or a list of the most common.)

I tried Google, and read that Redhat linux defaults to "localhost," and Toshiba laptops (Windows) default to Toshiba, and some Dells default to DELL+some model number.

Comment: I can't think of a single use for this information that doesn't make me cringe...

Comment: Were you sitting in a disco-industrial-raver bar, with your hot new friends, talking about "god", "love", "money", while passing around old UNIX manuals? Because that would have been awesome.

Comment: Hmmm. Passing around something.

Answer (score 0):

HPs will default to something like HP382811UX.

Comment: I don't know if it still does but Slackware used to default to darkstar. I never looked into why but something different to localhost.

Comment: @Richard [Dark Star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Star_%28song%29) is a Grateful Dead song. [Patrick Volkerding](http://www.absoluteastronomy.com/topics/Patrick_Volkerding) is, reportedly, a ["Dead Head"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadhead).